# PHP download file from CDN direct to client

Tags: php, download, cdn

I have problem with downloading files from my CDN. I moved all big files from hosting to CDN to save bandwidth but function in PHP is running on server and every download counts to bandwidth anyway. It's like traffic is going from CDN -> server (hosting) -> client. Is there any possible solution to go direct CDN -> client?
My download function:

```
function download($url) {
 header ("Content-type: octet/stream");
 header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$url.";");
 header("Content-Length: ".filesize($url));
 file_get_contents($url);
 exit();
}
```

After forcing this function I can see in log on CDN that download is from server (hosting) IP.

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: You would need to send an HTTP redirect to the CDN. But I don't know if you can force it to download instead of loading into the browser if you do that.

Comment: Can you arrange for the CDN to send the `Content-disposition: attachment` header?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly download it from CDN to client with masking. You need to use `header("Location: http://example.com/file.zip");` to download directly to client, but it will show original CDN URL to the client.

Answer (score 0):

So after few hours I found workaround:

1. After clicking download button I'm using AJAX function to get URL of file from CDN server
2. Then this URL is attached to download link element on page
3. jQuery function clicks on this link (on background) - force downloading
4. URL is removed from  element by jQuery